# What is the Correct Network Folder Address in Python on Linux or WSL?

Tags: python, linux, windows, networking, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I've been using VS Code on Windows to develop Python.
I've referenced a file excel on network folder:

```
file = r'\\192.168.1.100\Data\Project\Client\CTR01\Schedule.xlsx'
```

But when I'm using VS Code on WSL (Ubuntu) and the code cannot access address above.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\192.168.1.100\\Data\\Project\\Client\\CTR01\\Schedule.xlsx'
```

What is the correct code in Linux for the referenced file on network folder?
Do I need to import particular module or package?

FYI, username and password are not needed.
Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to mount the network drive beforehand :

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/192.168.1.100-Data
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\192.168.1.100\Data' /mnt/192.168.1.100-Data
```

Comment: This worked great for me. The only caveat is that it took a long time (10 seconds) to return from ls -al from the CLI in WSL2. I suspect it is the size of the directory since less populated directories returned quicker, so at least it isn't the network negotiation. Thanks!